# Is there a jenkins plugin to add a why-I-built-this remark, that will appear with 'started by [user]'?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When I run a manual build, I'd often like to mark it with documentation to show why I ran it. Is this feature available with a plugin?
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by adding a build parameter as a string, as above, then use the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) to set it from that parameter. We use something like this for the regex:

```
^\++ : BUILD DESCRIPTION : GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL=([^@\s]*)\S*, BUILD_USER_EMAIL=([^@\s]*)\S*, GERRIT_BRANCH=(\S*), GIT_COMMIT=(\S{8}).*$
```

and this for the description:

```
\1\2, \4, \3
```

As a result we get:

> jspain, 0ee3198b, master

or when it fails, we get:

> Failed due to timeout.
>
> wayvad, fc7bdf2a, master

this "Failed..." text comes from the [Build Timeout Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin)

Comment: this is great! One question on the capturing, \1\2 is only producing one output? (Or is it that jspain = js + pain?) I thought it would perhaps duplicate the emailid. Also, the descriptor setter noted there is a similar plugin to set the build name, as regex, to give a nice description in the GUI, eg '#13 v1.3.3 shafec', https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin

Comment: Look here: https://build.allseenalliance.org/ci/job/linux-js-verify/196/consoleFull search for GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL to see the output at the top and [description-setter] to see it at the bottom. Read-only config [here](https://build.allseenalliance.org/ci/job/linux-js-verify/configure-readonly/)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a plugin that can do this, and after a brief search I could not find one to do what you describe.

You can mimic this behavior by adding a string parameter in the job that takes a default value of `automatically started` when it's normally run, but that you can change to `my reasons for this build` when starting it manually.

You could then use a batch (or groovy or ) build step to print the contents of that parameter into the build log.  If you do some sort of SCM checkout I'm not sure how close you can get it to print to the line that contains the username that started the job, however you can click on the view parameters button in the job build and see what was in the field quickly without having to parse the logs.

The downside of this is that parameter would have to be added to each job.